# Task triggered by run

Tags: scala, sbt

If in my `build.sbt` I have the following code:

```
val example = TaskKey[Unit]("example")
example := Def.task[Unit] {
  streams.value.log.info("EXAMPLE")
}.triggeredBy(compile in Compile).value
```

When I execute `~ compile`, whenever a source changes I'll see in the console `EXAMPLE`.

**How to get the same behavior for `~ run arg1 arg2`?**

The difficulty I'm having in implementing this is because `run` is an `InputKey` as opposed to `compile in Compile` which is a `TaskKey`.

Answer (score 1):

You can have :

```
example in run := Def.task[Unit] {
  streams.value.log.info("EXAMPLE")
}.triggeredBy(compile in Compile).value
```

Comment: What if instead of `run` I have a different `InputKey` which I do not control?

Comment: Such as?.. can you give an example?

Comment: Example in "InputKey" :=, you should always be able to control your inputkeys.

Comment: I'm using [sbt-revolver](https://github.com/spray/sbt-revolver) in which `reStart` is an `InputKey` and I would like to execute a task whenever the server is restarted. However I don't seem to be able to do so.
If you depend on someone else library you cant control their `InputKeys`

Comment: If I execute `~compile` I see EXAMPLE in the logs even though I did not execute `run`.

Comment: Yeah, in your current code, it will definitely show EXAMPLE because you said it is triggered by compile in Compile, put run in Compile and it won't.

Comment: Here, this documentation will really help you. 

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Input-Tasks.html#Get+a+Task+from+an+InputTask

Comment: I just went to their documentation, sbt-revolver, and you can infact do anything you want in restart. You can use this syntax : 

run in reStart := Some("com.my.code")

And add your code into that  "code" class and it will work. It doesn't have to be in your build.sbt. You can run a class which basicallly does what you want it do.

Comment: That documentation won't work since I don't know the arguments to pass to `toTask` (eg: "~run arg1 arg2"). `run in reStart` is already executing a class (in my case a webserver) I want to execute another task `example` after that one executes.